# How to change string to float with many number after comma with jolt in Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

How to change string to float with many number after comma with jolt in Apache Nifi

```
  {
        "value": "0.000000123"
   }
```

i need output like:

```
{
  "value": 0.000000123
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't get such an output.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan is technically correct, but doesnt explain why. The reason being that it is possible to make this conversion for Doubles and Integers in JOLT, but NOT for Float values.

Answer (score 0):

If the value were an Integer, not a Float, using the "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta", and "value": "=toInteger, it would be possible. But for a floating point value, it does NOT look like that is possible using JOLT unfortunately.

An integer solution would be something similar to this: http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#modify-typeConversion